Can you typically get prescriptions fulfilled internationally? [Specifically Germany / UK]
I will travel to the UK from Germany today.
My German doctor is sending me a prescription, but it hadn't arrived by the time I left home, so I'll be unable to get it fulfilled before I leave the country.
If I have a friend post me the prescription from Germany to the UK, will a British pharmacy be able to fulfill it?

Note: I think your question is very different. your question is: "can a foreign prescription get fulfilled at home?". Which IMO is different, and I think the "at home" makes things more difficulty: you should be able to get a local prescription. On third countries (my experience) things seems easier, but I'm not sure about "at home" case.

Did the doctor know you may have to get it in a different country? If so international names or chemical content rather than local brand names should be used. But UK and Germany might have the same name for this medicine.

@GiacomoCatenazziI I live and work in Germany, that is my home.

@NeilTarrant: sorry: I read the question wrongly. So you are on normal case, and often they accept. Maybe they want to phone the doctor (but with similar timezone it should not be a problem). In any case it depends also on what you ask (risks, e.g. on potentially addictive substances).

The general answer is "no"; pharmacies won't normally be permitted to recognize foreign physicians' medical licenses nor their authorization to prescribe medication.  Any exceptions such as those mentioned in the answers will be the result of some explicit legislation or regulation that allows (or requires) recognition of specific foreign licensing schemes.

There is an EU project through which pharmacist will be able to consult the prescriptions that you have in that system; I am working into putting my local healthcare organization into it. That said, I do not know if the UK is involved, nor if it is already implanted in Germany so that prescriptions are already availble. If you have not tried yet, maybe you can check at any pharmacy near you to see if it is working.

I would not assume that you typically can get prescriptions fulfilled abroad, but in your specific case, it is likely possible. With some restrictions regarding controlled drugs, UK pharmacists are supposed to accept prescriptions issued by an approved professional in an EEA country, e.g. Germany:
Prescriptions issued in the EEA and Switzerland: guidance for pharmacists
There are two caveats you should be aware of:

German doctors have for a few years been able to issue electronic prescriptions. You can't expect that foreign pharmacies are able to work with these. From your question, it sounds though as if you are waiting for a paper prescription. I am not sure, if it is so urgent, why your German doctor did not right away issue an electronic prescription, which you could have immediately collected in any German pharmacy.

I would not expect all UK pharmacists to be aware that they may fulfil foreign prescriptions. It might help to refer unknowing pharmacists to the page I have linked above or you should take into account that you might visit more than one pharmacy before you find someone willing to hand out your medication.



It's worth noting that (even with an EHIC), cross-border prescriptions will have to be paid for at full cost at the point of sale (see https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/prescription-medicine-abroad/expenses-reimbursements/index_en.htm). Get a receipt, and (try to) get it reimbursed when you're back home.

@jcaron Depending on your German health insurance, it might even in Germany with a German prescription be necessary to pay the medication and then later be reimbursed by the insurance.

european-union, as the question is quite vague. For OP, this may be useful as they may be to take a day trip to Republic of Ireland.

Prescriptions issued in one EU country are valid elsewhere in EU too.
This however may require your doctor to issue a special type of prescription if the regular type does not have enough information. You should always inform them that you intend to use it abroad, as they can then know to include the generic name of the medication alongside any potentially missing information that'd be needed make it valid throughout EU.
In some cases an e-prescription may also be accepted, but only between some countries (too complex to include here).
Here's EU's own guidance on this: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/prescription-medicine-abroad/prescriptions/index_en.htm
And here's Ireland, Netherlands etc.

The dispensing of medication is however bound by local law and medicine availability.
For example, normal German prescriptions are valid for 28 days, but Czechia only recognizes prescriptions issued in the last 14 days. Czechia does not have to fill this prescription if it's past 14 days.
If the medication is not available in the country you're in, then they don't have to fill the prescription either. If there's local limits on dosage or amount that can be filled at once, those limits will be followed when dispensing your medication.
Pharmacies must follow EU law and fill the prescription if it fulfills all the mentioned requirements, but it can happen that they try to make up excuses to not do so. At least in Germany, there are various pharmacies, often around main train stations (Hauptbahnhof) that advertise as "international pharmacy", which advertise filling foreign prescriptions (from qualifying countries). If you struggle with regular pharmacies, try and see if there's one of these around you.

As for the costs, be prepared to pay out of pocket, and keep documentation to submit to your insurance at home. They may or may not pay in full (they may only pay up to what they'd've paid if you have filled it in the country).

"Prescriptions issued in one EU country are valid elsewhere in EU too." - Just as a note - I have had numerous times my presriptions rejected in German pharmacies (I am from an EU country) because they supposedly had no way to check if it is legit (the precriptions had the hospital stamp, doctor signature, the generic name of the medication and so on). So while this is claimed in theory also on the relevant websites that are supposed to inform you about this, in practice it is not always the case that they will let you use an EU prescription.

@lightxbulb If the prescription was up to requirements, then they were not fulfilling their legal obligations by doing so, but of course that can happen. It sounds like your case didn't fulfill them, as "direct contact details" is required to be on there, to allow the pharmacy to call them to confirm if necessary. If it was correct, then my recommendation is to go to pharmacies that advertise filling foreign prescriptions (here they usually call themselves "international pharmacy"). EU's own website suggests instead complaining to the relevant health administration if this happens.

(but also: German private prescriptions can be printed on any paper, don't have much information that lets one check if its legit, can even be handwritten, yet no German pharmacy complains with them IME. I do think the pharmacies you visited were being lazy, a not-unheard-of phenomenon with pharmacies and their more obscure obligations, apparently all German pharmacies must do compounding if prescription calls for it, but smaller or overworked pharmacies sometimes will try to get you to go to another pharmacy. Regardless, I added the info about international pharmacies in the post body.)

If all else fails, go to the closest Urgent Care
I've been in this problem before where an important medication got lost during a trip. I just found the closest urgent care center, walked in, explained my situation, and the doctor was able to prescribe me the medication. Assuming this isn't a medication that people often abuse, this should work without issues.
Depending on the specifics of the country you could also:

Make an appointment with a local doctor or another person authorized to prescribe medicine locally, such as a nurse-practitioner. As per @mdewey this is not realistic in the UK at the moment, but might be possible in other countries.
Stop by a pharmacy and ask. In some countries pharmacists might be able to get you a prescription on their own. In places where they aren't authorized to do this, they might be helpful in giving advice on how to see a doctor quickly, especially if its a pharmacy that serves a lot of tourists.
You can dial the local non-emergency medical number, such as 111 in the UK. Explain your situation and ask for guidance.


From personal experience between the UK and the Netherlands: it depends on the organisation prescribing the medication as well as on the pharmacy handing it out (and on the specific medication, something may not be legal in the country you're trying to fill the prescription but legal where it's prescribed. But I'll assume that this is not the case for you).
Your best bet typically is to try to get the foreign prescriber to work with your local doctor, and have them reissue the prescription in your country of residence.
While there are (as stated by others) efforts underway to get an EU wide system in place for referrals and prescriptions, this isn't in place yet (and the UK is no longer part of the EU, so they may not become a part of this if it ever gets off the ground.

Was your UK-NL experience post or pre-brexit?

@ave mostly post-Brexit.
